# Need to compare new date with datepicker

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datepicker

Im struggling with dates in javascript. Im going to compare some dates input but the user and the date the user input depends which list the information goes. My issue is comparing the system date and the date picker date. The system date shows the format of 'Tue Dec 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)' date picker shows 22/12/2015. How can i change the system date to match the date picker format so i can compare dates? I want to do it without jQuery(i know date picker goes against this).

Here my code so far for the date which basically is just setting the time to 00:00:00.

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
yesterday.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0);

console.log(today);


var dateTask = document.getElementById("date").value;

    console.log(dateTask);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the user input into a `Date` object. `22/12/2015` is not a valid datestring for the `Date` constructor so you have to parse it yourself.
You can do something like this:

```
const [day, month, year] = document.getElementById("date").value.split('/');
const dateTask = new Date(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

*Note: this code is very basic and needs an enhancement when you're parsing real user input.*

After that you can compare the dates like this:

```
today.getTime() === dateTask.getTime()
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me get the result i wanted. I had to change the dateSplits around as it was in an american date format from the date picker. What did you mean in your note at the bottom?? What enhancements would it need?? If you could go into a little detail please and i can read up on it from there.

`var dateSplit= document.getElementById("date").value.split('/'),
    dateTask = new Date(dateSplit[2],dateSplit[0]-1,dateSplit[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: @monkeyman905 If the user puts in `09/04` you will only have 2 array items, the code above will error because `dateSplit[2]` is not defined. You have to decide what you let through from user input. Btw your question included this date: `22/12/2015` so I assumed the first part was the day and not the month :)

Comment: yea totally my bad, i didn't realise till after. The dates didn't compare until i used the `if( today.getTime() === dateTask.getTime())` is this normal?  shouldn't `today === dateTask` return true?

Comment: @monkeyman905 Excuse me. The `==` or `===` compare the reference of the date. You can compare them with `.getTime()` method or `today >= dateTask && today <= dateTask`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need JQuery if you want a date-picker, but that's beside the point. I think the best approach is to parse the user input as a date using [Date.parse](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date/parse). You can then compare them as [unix epoch timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```js
"use strict";
var datePicker = document.querySelector('#date');
datePicker.addEventListener('change',function(){

  var udate = Date.parse(this.value);
  var sysdate = Date.now();
  document.querySelector('#d').innerText = udate;
  document.querySelector('#sys').innerText = sysdate;

});
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}
label, input, output {
  float: left;
}
label {
  clear: left;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="date">user input</label>
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
  <label for="d">user date</label>
  <output id="d" name="d" for="date"></output>
  <label for="sys">system date</label>
  <output id="sys" name="sys"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the real solution here — very useful demo and practical application of a Unix epoch timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string with str.split("/"); and construct Date in one of the ways that is pointed out here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

be careful months are from 0-11

Answer (score 0):

```
const datePicker = document.querySelector("#date");
const todayDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
const datePickerValue = new Date(datePicker.value).toLocaleDateString();

datePicker.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (datePickerValue === todayDate) {
    alert("");
  } else {
    alert("");
  }
});
```